# Address changed at contract deployment

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm fooling around on the testnet, and I made a contract with an "owner", input manually (not necessarily the sender) that has admin-like privileges.

When I deployed my contract I pasted my main address, but when the contract was deployed the address was different by 1 character! See for yourself, this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCNXe.png) shows the `owner` attribute and my account address.

This happened twice, with the same owner icon, and the same different character. I pasted and I know I did it right, it displayed my icon and everything.

What is the cause of this, and how do I fix it? Because I'm not the owner I can't do anything on my contract. It's not just having permissions, it includes functions that automatically sending tokens to the owner, etc.

The contract is an extension of [the token tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token), here is the contructor:

```
function MyToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol,
    address contractOwner
) {
      balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply; // Give the creator all initial tokens
      totalSupply = initialSupply;          // Update total supply
      name = tokenName;                    // Set the name for display purposes
      symbol = tokenSymbol;               // Set the symbol for display purposes
      decimals = decimalUnits;           // Amount of decimals for display purposes
      owner = contractOwner;
}
```